# Does NIST SP800-56C r2 forbid using NIST-approved two-step KDFs for not-all-at-once key-derivations?

Tags: nist, hkdf

NIST [SP800-56C r2](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Cr2.pdf) added `Section 5.3` which specifically addresses using a single `Extract` step followed by `m` `Expand` steps using the same key-derivation-key produced in the `Extract` step.

[image]

This is a very common widely-deployed scenario (ex. processing `master-key` in `Extract`, then generating multiple derived keys with `Expand` to ex. encrypt multiple files, or multiple plaintext chunks/frames, etc. The number of such subsequent calls to `Expand` is either very large, and/or unknown (depends on the data being streamed/processed).

In all such cases, derived-key `DKM-1` must be returned from `KDF` before deriving next key `DKM-2` and the `N` for `DKM-N` is unknown (but could often be bounded by ex. `2^64`).

The newly added `Section 5.3` states the following:

> The derived keying material, `DKM-1`, `DKM-2` , ... , and
> `DKM-m` **shall not** be output until all `m` of the bit strings have been
> successfully computed. If an error occurs during randomness extraction or key expansion, then this key-derivation method **shall not** output any derived keying material.

**Questions:**

Why was `Section 5.3` added? What is it trying to guard against (ie. is there a cryptographic or logical rationalization for it)? Does it prohibit using a single `Extract` followed by multiple `Expand` in a "streaming/online" manner, where `Expand` outputs are generated and used on as-needed basis (ie. not all at once)?

If `Section 5.3` indeed forbids such a common scenario of online/streaming derivation of multiple `Expand` from a single `Extract`, how can we implement such a scenario (deriving multiple keys from a single non-uniform-entropy/unknown-entropy master-key) in a NIST-compliant way (a scenario that normally calls for a two-step `KDF`)?